# Insert Row Into Composite Table With Hibernate Named Query

Tags: hibernate, spring, insert, hql, named-query

Does anyone know the correct syntax in HQL to insert a row into a composite table? or an example somehwere else?  Nothing online, man I miss Linq-To-Sql.

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery( name = "WebsiteAction.addActionWebsite", query = "INSERT INTO WebsiteAction 
(websiteActionPK, websiteActionPK) SELECT a.Id, w.Id FROM Action a, Website w WHERE a.Id = :actionid AND w.Id = :websiteid")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for bulk insertstatements is described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-direct). But this will only work if you try to insert into a table mapped to en entity. If WebsiteAction is just a join table, I think you'll have to use SQL rather than HQL.